# How to display a default home page?

Tags: jsf-2

Our application JSF2/weblogic10.3.4 has different client folders deployed in root context as below.

```
app->webapp->ClientA->index.jsf
           ->ClientB->index.jsf
```

If the user request our app with client name, we need to display the corresponding `index.jsf`.

If the browser request is http://server/ClientA, we should display http://server/ClientA/index.jsf

If the browser request is http://server/ClientB, we should display http://server/ClientB/index.jsf

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Register it as `<welcome-file>` in the `web.xml`.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

You only need to create empty files with exactly that name next to the existing `index.xhtml` files in the same folder, so that the container is fooled that those files really exist, otherwise you will still get 404s.

An alternative is to replace the `FacesServlet` URL pattern of `*.jsf` by `*.xhtml` so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

```xml
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: can that be applied to all different folders what we have?i mean clientA, ClientB , we have app in root context

Comment: The `<welcome-file>` is not folder-specific. It applies to every folder.