# How to declare default .xhtml page in JSF2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, tomcat7

I have created a JSF 2.0 application as shown in the [Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html) with the Eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 7.0.32.

In this application I have two pages:

1. login.xhtml
2. welcome.xhtml

From `login.xhtml` I am navigation to `welcome.xhtml`.

And I have declared the `login.xhtml` as the welcome page in my `web.xml`.

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

And also defined the `url-pattern` for `Faces Servlet` as:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now I am having two issues:

1. When I am accessing the URL `http://localhost:8080/LibraryInformationSystem/`  I can see the login page, but after login, when I am being navigated to the welcome.xhtml, the URL is changing to `http://localhost:8080/LibraryInformationSystem/login.xhtml` not `http://localhost:8080/LibraryInformationSystem/welcome.xhtml`; but if I manually browse `http://localhost:8080/LibraryInformationSystem/welcome.xhtml`, it is also showing same thing. My question is why the URL is not changing? Is it the right way to define the default page? I have found information from two other SO threads, first one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295878/how-to-display-a-default-home-page) and the second one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343086/jsf-make-a-jsf-a-default-page-to-go-to-when-type-mydomain-com).
2. The second problem is, when I am running the application from Eclipse and when it launches the application to its internal browser, I can see the login page, but if I shutdown the server running from Eclipse and run the Tomcat from the batch file startup.bat which resides in bin folder and export the application as a war file and deploy it into the webapps folder, sometime I can see the login page, sometime I am having the Tomcat's HTTP Error - 404 page, from Firefox or Chrome. If I close the startup.bat and delete the myapplication.war and myapplication folder from the webapps folder, then again start the server from startup.bat and again export the war from Eclipse I can see the login page, in this case no 404 error. Why it is happening?

Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Comment: +1, if whoever did it feels strongly enough, he'll come back to red own vote and explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About point 1), JSF breaks the HTTP semantics. It should be using a GET to provide the contents of `http://localhost:8080/LibraryInformationSystem/welcome.xhtml`, but JSF uses POST so the URL does not change. You can do a `Post-Redirect-Get` to update the URL, but it is not how JSF works by default.

About point 2, you should avoid making two questions in the same SO question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I thought both the problem is related. Anyway I will create a new thread.